# Variable not initialized in default constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, lombok, default-constructor

I have this class:

```java
import lombok.Data;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

// tag::code[]
@Data
@Document
public class Image {

    @Id final private String id;
    final private String name;
}
// end::code[]
```

My understanding is that `@Data` should create a constructor for all final fields by default. However when I run my application I get this error:

```
error: variable id not initialized in the default constructor
        @Id final private String id;
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Do you have `enabling annotation processing` on?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 how do I check that?

Comment: In intellij: Settings -> Build,Execute,Deployment -> Compile -> Annotation Processors

Comment: Try a trivial thing like a class with a single `@Getter` annotated field and check whether the getter exists. This will tell you whether your Lombok setup works. Without knowing this, nothing useful can be done.

Comment: As it seems there should not even be a default constructor for your `Image` class. Maybe part of stack trace tells more about this error is it related to `Image`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My understanding is that @Data should create a constructor for all final fields by default. Error: variable id not initialized in the default constructor `@Id final private String id;` Why would this be happening?

Yes! you are right! @Data annotation generates a parameterized constructor for final fields, generates setters for all non-final fields and getters for both types of fields.

In your case, your generated constructor should look like this,

```
public Image(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

//getters for both fields
```

As your constructor not able to initialize the final fields - seems `Lombok` is not being set up properly - you can verify it by checking your `Image.class` in the `target/classes` directory with the same package(as you have it in your src *except you have defined the location explicitly through config file*). If it's not being generated, verify your dependency, Lombok plugin, you may want to explore Lombok [configuration](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) for further set-up.

Comment: I added `annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'` to my `build.gradle` dependencies. Issue seems to be resolved now. Thanks for that explanation. It was a big help.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and it appears I haven't added the `annotationProcessorPath` to lombok during it's installation, similar to what @runnerpaul mentioned.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [@RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)